# Установка wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь установить wordpress. Открывается установка, ввожу данные для конекта в БД, жму next, потом открывается - /wp-admin/install.php и там 500 ошибка. Не понятно почему.

Что я выявнил, если меняешь сервер для БД в конфиге на любой помимо localhost или 127.0.0.1, то WordPress начинает писать, что у меня не правильный сервер.

.htaccess нет.

Раньше в конфиге было написано:

```
Options -Indexes
            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=URL:%{REQUEST_URI}]
            RequestHeader append X_ORIGINAL_URL %{URL}e
            RequestHeader edit X_ORIGINAL_URL (.*),.* $1



            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]


            AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

В итоге не знаю в чем проблема, как быть?

В логах пишет:

> [Wed Apr 24 21:42:14 2013] [error] [client XXXXXXXXXXX] File does not
>   exist: /xxxxxxx/vil

Конфиг:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.org
    ServerAlias xxx.org www.xxx.org
    DocumentRoot /home/www/xxx/
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Попробуйте в `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`  
включить для корневой папки сайта опцию **FollowSymLinks**. Например так:  

    <Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
В Windows пути могут отличаться.

Comment: Тут не совсем понятно, чт вы делаете. Переносите или устанавливаете. Уточните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно убедится включён ли mod_rewrite на сервере.

Comment: Это не обязательное условие.

Answer (score 1):

добрый день 
при установке wordpress, не надо лезть в код.
сначала зайдите на хостинг и создайте базу  данных:
"Создать новую MySQL базу и пользователя базы данных"
вы получите имя и пароль а также имя сервера, которые вставите в нужные отделы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и всего делов :)